# How to add a UI QWidget to a UI QWidget?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qt-designer

Completely using QT Designer. I've created a `QWidget` to encapsulate a collection of controls. I now want to use this `QWidget` several times in the `QMainWindow` form.

How do I 'put' my `QWidget` onto the `QMainWindow` using QT Designer only?

Shouldn't this just be a simple drag and drop operation? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [promote widgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets).

Simply drag and drop QWidget into your mainwindow with QtDesigner.

Right click on it and press `promote to` In the dialog fill in your created widget's Class name (header should be filled in automatically if it doesn't match edit accordingly) press `add` and `promote`.

Now build and run your application and you should see your widget with collection of controls.

[image: promoting]

Comment: I can achieve this almost by promoting a QWidget with (Base: QWidget, Class: Ui::MyWidget, header: ui_mywidget.h). But compilation fails - The auto-generated class for MyWidget doesn't contain the copy constructor and member functions expected. I assume because it is not a sub-class of QWidget in the generated code.

Comment: could you provide "your" QWidget's with collection of controls relevant source?

Comment: I don't know that I have anything to provide. The VS2015 solution is empty (aka as created by the create QT GUI project wizard). The QMainWindow ui is empty and the QWidget has just one drag and dropped QPushButton inside it. Literally everything is auto-generated.

Comment: Maybe VS2015 solution is the problem. I have included gif how it looks on QtCreator

Comment: `Ui::MyWidget` is indeed not a `QWidget` subclass and cannot be used for promoting. You need to create a Qt Designer Form Class (as opposed to Qt Designer Form) for your inner form, so that Qt Creator creates a `QWidget` subclass for you that contains the inner form. Use that `QWidget` subclass when promoting the widget.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov That was bang on. I see where I was going wrong now - I didn't realise I had to manually link this. It's working fine now that I'm promoting the widget to MyWidgetClass instead of Ui::MyWidget. Thanks.